# CSS background attachment fixed clipping image

Tags: html, css

Image is 328x328 pixels https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpKuw.jpg?s=328&g=1

width of my div is 984px (328x3).

For some reason when I used `fixed` for the background attachment it clips the image but when the default value `scroll` is used the image is perfect. Why is this?

Not only is it clipped but when I resize to window to full display the image disappears!

```css
.test {
 background-color: cyan;
 height: 1720px;
 width: 984px;
 background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpKuw.jpg?s=328&g=1);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:  right top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `fixed` is fixed with regard to the **viewport**. `background-position:  right top; background-attachment: fixed;` will put the image in the top/right of the viewport when the element is in view. And since the element the background is applied to isn't as wide as the viewport (depending on your screen size), the background image is clipped.  Remove the `width` from the element so that it can be in the top/right corner of the viewport and the background is fixed in the top/right corner as long as the element is in the top/right corner, too.

```css
.test {
    background-color: cyan;
    height: 1720px;
    /*width: 984px;*/
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpKuw.jpg?s=328&g=1);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:  right top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'></div>
```